# Spock Spring inject mock and bean via constructor

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, spock

I'm looking for way how to inject beans and mock in single constructor.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

private EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider;
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public SomeService(EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider, RestTemplate restTemplate){
  this.endpointUrlProvider = endpointUrlProvider;
  this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

Test:

```
class SomeTest extends Specification {

@Autowired
EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider

RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
    postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
 }

SomeService someService = new SomeService(endpointUrlProvider, restTemplate)

//some tests
    }
```

When I fire test my endpointUrlProvider in someService is null. What I did wrong  ? What is the best way to test this?

Comment: Should `EndpointUrlProvider` also be a mock or a real bean?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are trying to do partial mocking. To inject Spring beans, first you will need `TestContextManager`. Therefore, run the test with `SpringRunner` or `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. This should do the work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider;

    @Before
    public setUp() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        SomeService someService = new SomeService(endpointUrlProvider, restTemplate);
    }
}
```